# Creating dictionary need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
managers = ['john', 'karl', 'ricky']
sites = ['site1', 'site2', 'site3']
```

I also have a json file for each manager:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "employee1",
      "user": {
        "location": "site1"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "employee2",
      "user": {
        "location": "site1"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "employee3",
      "user": {
        "location": "site2"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "employee4",
      "user": {
        "location": "site3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So now, I want to create a dictionary by to categorize data by **site**! which is making it challenging for me. The output I need is to show employees for each site.

Here is the code I have:

```
myDict = dict()

for j in managers:
    for i in range(len(sites)):
        with open(""+j+"-data.json", 'r') as jasonRead:
            json_object = json.loads(jasonRead.read())

            for result in json_object['results']:
                site = (result['user']['location'])

            for employee, manager in map(str.split, str(site), managers[i]):
                myDict.setdefault(managers[i], []).append(site)
```

The error I get:

```
  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
    for employee, manager in map(str.split, str(site), managers[i]):
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: `map(str.split, str(site), managers[i])` makes no sense. This will call `str(site)[0].split(managers[i][0])`, `str(site)[1].split(managers[i][1])`, and so on. So you're trying to split 1 character of `site` using 1 character from `managers[i]` as the delimiter.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: you could show what result you expect for your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping over `sites`, just test if the site of the employee is in the list.

The keys of the resulting dictionary should be the site names, not the manager names.

```
mydict = {}

for manager in managers:
    with open(f'{manager}-data.json') as jasonRead:
        json_object = json.load(jasonRead)
    for result in json_object['results']:
        site = result['user']['location']
        if site in sites:
            mydict.setdefault(site, []).append(result['id'])

print(mydict)
```